# Track mouse over event in Windows CE

Tags: mfc, windows-ce

How to track the Mouse Over event while moving Mouse over Menu or some other window?
I have tried TrackMouseEvent, But it's not supported by Win CE. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the Tooltip control:

[MSDN Article about ToolTips in WinCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926239.aspx)

Or directly work with the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages and do it yourself. It's not very hard to with mouse messages because you can use the WindowFromPoint() function to know what window you mouse is hovering over.